# Python не получается сделать хеш пароля

Tags: python, хеширование

Я хочу сделать типо "хеш" пароля, ну чтобы я писал допустим букву A и мне возвращалось значение 01, или например Z = 26, C = 3 и т.д. То есть мне нужно чтобы когда я писал букву то сохранялось значение букву по нумерации алфавита и потом написался полученный зашифрованный пароль.

```
def hash(a, b):
    if pw == a.lower():
        hash_pw = hash_pw
        hash_pw += b
    if pw == "go" or pw == "done" or pw == "ok":
        print(hash_pw)
while(True):
    pw = input()
    hash("A", "01")
    hash("B", "02")
    hash("C", "03")
    hash("D", "04")
    hash("E", "05")
    hash("F", "06")
    hash("G", "07")
    hash("H", "08")
    hash("I", "09")
    hash("J", "10")
    hash("K", "11")
    hash("L", "12")
    hash("M", "13")
    hash("N", "14")
    hash("O", "15")
    hash("P", "16")
    hash("Q", "17")
    hash("R", "18")
    hash("S", "19")
    hash("T", "20")
    hash("U", "21")
    hash("V", "22")
    hash("W", "23")
    hash("X", "24")
    hash("W", "25")
    hash("Z", "26")
```

Comment: В вопросе не указано никакой ошибки

Comment: Начнем с того, что замена символа на некое число - это не хэш.   Во-вторых: "Я хочу сделать типо "хеш" пароля"  - ну хочется -  сделай, вопрос-то в чем? В третьих -  в коде СИНТАКСИЧЕСКАЯ ошибка.  Т.е. вы либо код ни разу не запускали, либо синтаксис Python даже не пробовали учить. Так причем-тут форум?

Comment: можешь пожалуйста пояснить значение переменной hash_pw. Непонятно

Comment: `pw = input(); print(''.join([str(ord(l.lower())-ord('a')+1).zfill(2) for l in pw]))`

Comment: @splash58 спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если Вас правда интересует безопасность сохраняемых паролей, используйте настоящий хеш (хотя бы sha256), а не кодировку по номерам букв, как делают в первом классе.

**Немного про саму суть хеша:**

Хеш это набор символов, созданный на основе Ваших данных, предполагается что единственный способ узнать данные, зная хеш, это перебор всех вариантов

Пример, строка: `Hello world`, это `64ec88ca00b268e5ba1a35678a1b5316d212f4f366b2477232534a8aeca37f3c` (sha256)

Судя по Вашему вопросу, Вы хотите сохранить зашифрованный пароль. Я надеюсь Вы понимаете зачем это нужно, поскольку судя по Вашему способу, этот пароль узнать легче, чем посчитать в уме 16*34.

Вот пример кода шифрования набора символов на python:

```js
from hashlib import sha256

password = 'Здесь Ваш пароль'

crypto_password = sha256(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

print(crypto_password) # Выводим зашифрованный пароль
```

**Как использовать зашифрованные пароли в реальности**

1.Пользователь регистрируется на Вашем ресурсе (сайт, приложение или ещё что-нибудь) вводит свой пароль

2.**Вы не сохраняете пароль в открытом виде**, Вы шифруете его используя хеш.

3.Проверка пароля. Когда пользователь снова вводит пароль, вы опять шифруете его и проверяете на равенство с зашифрованным паролем которых хранится у Вас, из пункта 2

Answer (score -1):

На данный момент не могу понять в чем именно проблема и суть программы.

Могу сразу указать на несколько явных проблем.

Судя по всему, `hash_pw` это глобальная переменная. Её **НЕЛЬЗЯ** просто так изменять в функциях. Необходимо применять `global hash_pw`, что бы её можно было менять в функции.

Не надо делать действия типа: `variable = variable`.

Я примерно попытался угадать что вы хотели сделать, и вот код:

```
hash_pw = 'hash_pw - '
def hash(a, b):
    global hash_pw
    if pw == a.lower():
        hash_pw += b
    if pw == "go" or pw == "done" or pw == "ok":
        print(hash_pw)
while(True):
    pw = input()
    hash("A", "01")
    hash("B", "02")
    hash("C", "03")
    hash("D", "04")
    hash("E", "05")
    hash("F", "06")
    hash("G", "07")
    hash("H", "08")
    hash("I", "09")
    hash("J", "10")
    hash("K", "11")
    hash("L", "12")
    hash("M", "13")
    hash("N", "14")
    hash("O", "15")
    hash("P", "16")
    hash("Q", "17")
    hash("R", "18")
    hash("S", "19")
    hash("T", "20")
    hash("U", "21")
    hash("V", "22")
    hash("W", "23")
    hash("X", "24")
    hash("Y", "25") # У вас было W, а не Y
    hash("Z", "26")
```

Возможно, перечисления всех букв можно запихнуть в цикл:

```
letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
for i in range(len(letters)):
   hash(letters[i], str(i + 1).rjust(2))
```

Comment: у меня пишет hash_pw бесконечно с вашим кодом, но никак не сам зашифрованный пароль.

Comment: какой зашифрованный пароль? По вопросу практически не понятно.

Comment: я нашел некоторые ошибки, сделал некоторые улучшения стиля кода, но вы сами не задали в вопросе проблему

Comment: во вторых до правки там была маленькая ошибка, я её исправил

Comment: а про ord() ничего не слышали? Зачем городить огород.